# Download JSON in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Attempted to follow this nice example in React https://jsfiddle.net/cowboy/hHZa9/ by creating a state variable that gets updated with an async call. When the link is rendered and I click on the link - it says network error.

```
// constructor

      this.state = {
        linkReady: false,
        data: {}
      };

// ***
      show() {
        return (
          <a href={`data: ${this.state.data} `} download={"data.json"}>Download JSON</a>
        );
      }

      download() {
         this.props.downloadRequest({action: "download"}).then(
            (obj) => {
              this.setState({
                linkReady: true,
                data: "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj))
              });
            }
          );
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

After some investigating I found that the problem is the object returned from the server is too large. I made the object smaller and it works.

Since I don't expect special characters in my object - I removed `encodeURIComponent` and I am able to download the large file.

If there are better solutions I would like to know.

Comment: **1.** Why the **download** attribute in your `<a/>`? **2.** Why do you init **data** as an object and then assign it a **string**? **3.** Could you be more specific with the error is thrown when you click the anchor?

Comment: @jpacareu I made one small edit in the code. 1. I tried to follow the example. 2. I did not think it matters as I get the same error when I initialize as a string. 3. The file "data.json" starts to download then I get "Failed - Network error"

Comment: Well not sure but maybe one of the issues could be that you are including a plus sign (+) inside the template, probably a typo when copying from the example. What if:  **<a href={`data: '${this.state.data}' `} download="data.json">Download JSON</a>**

Comment: Check what I did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jpaca/kfjz5tae/1/) using template strings, I was having the same issue and the problem was with the **href**

Comment: @jpacareu Thank you for the help. Turns out my object is too large.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should check if your server has secure connection, when you are making request (I assume, you making an async request upon `downloadRequest`).

Also, you should remove plus sign (`+`) in your `href` attribute. You are using string interpolation so you don't need it.

```
href={`data: ${this.state.data}`}
```

Another thing (I don't know how it implemented currently due to not seeing full code, but) it to be sure that link is ready - so I advice you to create some conditions before rendering link.

The last one - I've created working sandbox for you - it might help you. [Click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/4zp9nlnk19).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. The sandbox helped a lot. It turns out that my object is too large and it is failing somehow.

Comment: @EdvBeq you are welcome! If you have any additional questions - do not hesistate to ask.